# Logging .sql file output to log file in shell script

Tags: sql, shell

I have an sql file being called from shell script, and I want to capture the output of the execution into a log file. I am trying to capture by appending redirecting to log file like this `>> log.txt` but it is not working.

What do I need to do to fix it?

```
sqlplus -s ${USER}/${PWD}@${DATABASE} << EOF
@${LOADDIR}/VV_validation.sql
EOF'
```

Comment: There's at least a decent chance that `sqlplus -s ${USER}/${PWD}@${DATABASE} << EOF >> log.txt 2>&1` would do the job.  The `2>&1` sends standard error (file descriptor 2) to the same place that standard output (file descriptor 1) is going, namely the `log.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sqlplus -s ${USER}/${PWD}@${DATABASE}
spool your_file_name.log
@@${LOADDIR}/VV_validation.sql
spool off
```

Comment: this is working, but spool is overwriting my log file, which was written already by previous statements.... is there anyway i can append ?

Comment: I tried with APPEND like this 'sqlplus -s ${USER}/${PWD}@${DATABASE}
spool your_file_name.log APPEND
@@${LOADDIR}/VV_validation.sql  
spool off' and it worked... thanks @StephaneM